# Referencing a File from a Test

Tags: unit-testing, rust

In `src/skyline.rs` I have the following code

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn get_skyline(buildings: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {
        
    }
}
```

In `tests/skyline.rs` I have the following code

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod skyline {
 
    #[test]
    fn one_building() {
        let building1 = vec![1,2,2];
        let buildings = vec![building1];

        let expected_skyline = vec![vec![1,2], vec![2,0]];
        assert_eq!(get_skyline(buildings), expected_skyline);
    }
}
```

When I run `cargo test`, I get the error

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `get_skyline` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:10:20
   |
10 |         assert_eq!(get_skyline(buildings), expected_skyline);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

I'm new to Rust so I'm not even sure if I have my project structure correct here.  How do I reference the file I am testing in the test file?

Comment: `/tests` is for integration tests, use functions like a different crate would use your crate, including the `use` statements. Or more likely put your unit tests inside of `src/skyline.rs` and add `use super::*;` to the `#[cfg(test)] mod skyline`.

Comment: Also check out [Writing Automated Tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-00-testing.html)